# value sequence is not a member of cats.Applicative[F]

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm migrating some scalaz based code to typelevel cats.

project/plugins.sbt

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

build.sbt

```scala
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-deprecation", "-Xlint", "-Xfatal-warnings", "-Ypartial-unification")
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
```

dependency in old scalaz based code is

`libraryDependencies += "com.github.julien-truffaut" %%% "monocle-macro" % "1.4.8"`

This is old scalaz-code based implementation which I want to migrate to cats.

```scala
import scalaz.Applicative
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._
import scala.language.higherKinds
import monocle.PTraversal

def letterTraversal(predicate: Char ⇒ Boolean): PTraversal[String, String, Char, Char] = new PTraversal[String, String, Char, Char] {
         override def modifyF[F[_]: Applicative](f: Char ⇒ F[Char])(s: String): F[String] = {
           Applicative[F].sequence(s.toList map {
             case x if predicate(x) ⇒ f(x)
             case x ⇒ Applicative[F].point(x)
           }).map(_.mkString)
         }
     }
```

dependency in new code cats based code is

`libraryDependencies += "com.github.julien-truffaut" %%% "monocle-macro" % "2.0.0"`

This is my new code

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds
import monocle.PTraversal
import cats.Applicative
import cats.implicits._

    def letterTraversal(predicate: Char ⇒ Boolean): PTraversal[String, String, Char, Char] = new PTraversal[String, String, Char, Char] {
            override def modifyF[F[_]: Applicative](f: Char ⇒ F[Char])(s: String): F[String] = {
              Applicative[F].sequence(s.toList map {
                case x if predicate(x) ⇒ f(x)
                case x ⇒ Applicative[F].point(x)
              }).map(_.mkString)
            }
        }
```

```
When I do `sbt clean compile` I get the below error -
```

> [error] /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/OS/reftree/demo/jvm/src/main/scala/reftree/demo/Data.scala:07:22: value sequence is not a member of cats.Applicative[F]
>
> [error]       Applicative[F].sequence(s.toList map {
>
> [error]                      ^
> [error] one error found
>
> [error] (demoJVM / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
>
> [error] Total time: 32 s, completed May 27, 2021, 4:36:58 PM

Why I'm not getting the sequence function for Applicative[F] even though I added `import cats.implicits._` in scope?

Comment: cats Applicative doesn't have sequence method. It's in `Traverse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to write that would be this:

```
import cats.syntax.all._
…
          s.toList.traverse {
            case x if predicate(x) ⇒ f(x)
            case x ⇒ x.pure[F]
          }.map(_.mkString)
```